# Get all contents of div including new inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a div which have 3 inputs:

```
<div class="excelPreview">
  <a href="#" id="getContent" class="btn btn-primary">get</a>
  <a href="#" id="calculate" class="btn btn-primary">calculate</a>
  <div class="getThis">
    Title
    <div>ID</div>
    <div>Name</div>
    <p>Content here....</p>
    <input type="text" id="num1"> + 
    <input type="text" id="num2"> = 
    <input type="text" id="total">
  </div>
</div>
```

the result of num1 is added to num2 and put in the total textbox. I use this to add

```
$( "#calculate" ).on( "click", function() {
            num1 = $("#num1").val();
            num2 = $("#num2").val();
            total = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
            $("#total").val(total);
    });
```

I use this code to get the html contents:

```
var cont = $('.getThis').html();
```

but it only gets the content not the values of textbox included like this
Title

```
<div>ID</div>
    <div>Name</div>
    <p>Content here....</p>
    <input type="text" id="num1"> + 
    <input type="text" id="num2"> = 
    <input type="text" id="total">
```

I want the result is should be: 
Title

```
<div>ID</div>
  <div>Name</div>
  <p>Content here....</p>
  <input type="text" id="num1" value="OfWhatIInput"> + 
  <input type="text" id="num2" value="OfWhatIInput"> = 
  <input type="text" id="total" value="OfWhatIsTheResult">
```

Comment: Currently in your input no value and you can not get total like this.Please clear your question first.

Comment: @NikunjChotaliya sorry Ive updated it I only what to get the value of all elements. Including the inputed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `clone`. `clone` will copy the whole div with all the events also.

```
$('#getContent').on('click', function() {
  var cont = $('.getThis').clone(true);
  $(".excelPreview").append(cont);
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j61t7qww/)

Comment: Youre right! But is there a way to convert this to string..because I want to store it on Database

Comment: In that case the values will not be present in this way.

Comment: can I convert the result to string?

Comment: For converting only to html your method is enough. But you need to modify the string with adding `value` attributes from the object,

Comment: Yes ur awesome! On my method I get string but not included the result of the total and what I inputted. Please help

Comment: Ill accept ur answer bcuz i think i the result is string. To be fair ill accept it and you answer my question

Answer (score 1):

I have done this by using `keyup` event. Any changes in your input will reflect directly in your sum.

I did some changes by adding `class="demo"` on your input style

```
<div class="excelPreview">
  <a href="#" id="getContent" class="btn btn-primary">get</a>
  <a href="#" id="calculate" class="btn btn-primary">calculate</a>
  <div class="getThis">
    Title
    <div>ID</div>
    <div>Name</div>
    <p>Content here....</p>
    <input type="text" class="demo" id="num1"> + 
    <input type="text" class="demo" id="num2"> = 
    <input type="text" id="total">
  </div>
</div>
```

Your JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".demo" ).keyup(function() {
     var textInput1 = $('#num1').val();
     var textInput2 = $('#num2').val();
     var total = parseInt(textInput1) + parseInt(textInput2); 
    //erase parseInt and check srting input addition
     $('#total').val(total);
  });
});
```

Also you can find solution here https://jsfiddle.net/zfb37pfp/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum=$('#num2).val()+$('#num2).val();
$('#total).val(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the values of the text boxes, you need to use the way mentioned.

```
var num1 = $('#num1').val();
var num2 = $('#num2').val();
var total = $('#num1').val()+$('#num2').val();
$('#total').val(total);
```

Try complete example as given below:

```
<div class="excelPreview">
  <a href="#" id="getContent" class="btn btn-primary">get</a>
  <a href="#" id="calculate" class="btn btn-primary">calculate</a>
  <div class="getThis">
    Title
    <div>ID</div>
    <div>Name</div>
    <p>Content here....</p>
    <input type="text" id="num1"> + 
    <input type="text" id="num2"> = 
    <input type="text" id="total">
    <input type="button" name="click" id="click" onclick="a()">
  </div>
  <script src="http://x.dpstatic.com/j/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  function a(){
        var num1 = $('#num1').val();
        var num2 = $('#num2').val();
        var total = parseInt($('#num1').val())+parseInt($('#num2').val());
        $('#total').val(total);
}
  </script>
```

Let me know if more information needed.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Sorry but this is not I want..I want to get contents of div including the value I input and result in a string.

Comment: to get complete HTML, you can use var cont = $('.getThis').html(); but that way you can not get value of inputs. getting html and getting value of inputs are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

I think 1 hack is to

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var cont = $('.getThis').clone().find('input:text').attr('value', function() {
    return this.value;
  }).end().html();
  snippet.log(cont)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<div class="excelPreview">
  <a href="#" id="getContent" class="btn btn-primary">get</a>
  <a href="#" id="calculate" class="btn btn-primary">calculate</a>
  <div class="getThis">
    Title
    <div>ID</div>
    <div>Name</div>
    <p>Content here....</p>
    <input type="text" id="num1" />+
    <input type="text" id="num2" />=
    <input type="text" id="total" />
  </div>
</div>
<button>Test</button>
```

Comment: Sorry not working It is b0s3 answer is right but lack. Can I convert it into string of what is the result so that I can store it on Database.

Comment: @GoperLeoZosa do you want the `getThis` element also in the html

Comment: @GoperLeoZosa which part is not working... you are getting the updated html with value attribute

Comment: I want to get the value on string